# My datagrid's selection is lost when updating my database from the grid's bound dataset. Any workarounds?

Tags: c#, ado.net, datagrid, concurrency, dataset

I am using Xceed's Datagrid, bound to a dataset. I want to update the database when the datagrid's RowEditEnd is called. The problem is that in order to avoid concurrency violations when updating, I have to clear the dataset after update and refill it, like this:

```
public void UpdateDatabaseFromDataSet()
{
    adapter.Update(exampleDataSet);
    exampleDataSet.Clear();
    adapter.Fill(exampleDataSet);
}
```

I think I have to do this because my dataset's primary autoincrement column "ID" does not match the values generated by the database. When I clear the dataset, it clears the datagrid and its selected cell. This is very annoying since, if you edit a cell and hit enter or a directional key, the cell and database will update fine, but your selection gets reset instead of navigating to the next row/cell. This makes entering data by hand very cumbersome.

Here is the method that creates the dataset:

```
public void InitDataSet(int tableid)
{
    cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM table_" + tableid, con);
    adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
    cb = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(adapter);

    try
    {

        exampleDataSet = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(exampleDataSet);
        prodDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[0].AutoIncrementSeed = -1;
        prodDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[0].AutoIncrementStep = -1;

        currenttableID = tableid;
    }
    catch (ApplicationException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Encountered an error.", "Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Note that I have tried setting the tables autoincrementseed and autoincrementsteps to -1 but  I still get concurrency violations if I don't refill the dataset.

I would really like my datagrid to work the way it does if I do not clear and refill the dataset. Is there anyway to avoid the concurrency violations I'm running into? Am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks for your help.
-Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand the complete problem but I might be able to give you something
When you **don't clear** the dataset and call "fill" it'll try to "merge" the records from the DB with the existing records. The clear forces your grid to refresh I guess.. losing the selected row.

With
Adapter.FillLoadOption = LoadOption.PreserveChanges (or other);
You can influence how records from the db that are changed are merged with the dataset.

Now there is one problem left and that is to determine the new **autoinc** value when an insert has taken place. You can catch the **Adapter.RowUpdated**

```
void Adapter_RowUpdated(object sender, SqlRowUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.StatementType==StatementType.Insert)
            {

                Select last autoinc value with @@Identity  
                e.Row["ID"] = last autoinc value
            } 
        }
```

So :

- Don't clear de datatable
- Catch rowupdated and get the latest autoinc value in the db in put it in the new row
- Evt. call fill to see if other users have made changes

Comment: Yeah, I apologize for the question not being super clear. Thank you very much for your suggestions, looks like they may solve my problem. I will try what you suggested when I get home next week and let you know how it went.

Thanks again.

Comment: I accepted your answer since you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks a lot for your help Julian.

I posted the actual code used in another answer below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that ended up working for me, putting it here for other's benefits.

Here's my data providers update method (note that I was able to remove the extra fill call):

```
public void UpdateDatabaseFromDataSet()
{
    adapter.Update(exampleDataSet);
}
```

And here is the RowUpdated event I'm using:

```
void adapter_RowUpdated(object sender, System.Data.Common.RowUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
    {
        SQLiteCommand cmdNewID = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT last_insert_rowid()", con);
        e.Row["RowID"] = cmdNewID.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```